# Missing number treated as zero :(

Tags: algorithmicx

Bonjour, quelqu'un (une) pourrait-il (elle) me dire où est le problème dans ce code en `LaTeX` ?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[grey,utopia]{quotchap}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Algorithme\\
\STATE Debut\\
\STATE Trier les $w_{i}$ dans l'ordre décroissant ;\\
\STATE Prendre les t\^{a}ches dans cette ordre ;\\
$w\leftarrow \{w_{1},...,w_{n}\} $;\\
\STATE Tant que ( $w\neq \emptyset$ ) Faire \\
$W_{k} \leftarrow max \; \{w\} $ ;\\
$ w \leftarrow w\{W_{k}\}$ ;\\
\STATE Fin Tant que \\
\STATE \quad Retourner $W_{k}$;\\
\STATE Fin
%\end{verbatimtab}
%\end{listing}
\end{algorithmic}
%\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

l'erreur affichée est :

```
Missing number treated as zero
```

Translation: Hi, could someone tell me where the problem is in this `LaTeX` code? The resulting error message is `Missing number treated as zero`.

Comment: Please, could you ask your question in English, not everybody understands French here

Comment: Note I have corrected your example so that it can reproduce the error, but the error is the _second_ error you get. later errors are often spurious, you should fix the first error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \algorithmic already defined.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If `algpseudocode` is not included, then there is no error message at all

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence yes that's the answer, do you want to post?:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: No, I leave such one-line - answers to you :-P

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: KarlKoeller was faster than you :-P

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9):

You are loading both `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode` which are not compatible.

Since your code is written in `algorithmic` style, simply remove the line

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

Also note that most of the `\\` are meaningless, since `\STATE` already starts a new line, so your code should be:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[grey,utopia]{quotchap}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Algorithme
\STATE Debut
\STATE Trier les $w_{i}$ dans l'ordre décroissant ;
\STATE Prendre les t\^{a}ches dans cette ordre ;\\
$w\leftarrow \{w_{1},...,w_{n}\} $;\\
\STATE Tant que ( $w\neq \emptyset$ ) Faire \\
$W_{k} \leftarrow max \; \{w\} $ ;\\
$ w \leftarrow w\{W_{k}\}$ ;
\STATE Fin Tant que
\STATE \quad Retourner $W_{k}$;
\STATE Fin
%\end{verbatimtab}
%\end{listing}
\end{algorithmic}
%\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @yasmineBen You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Small side note: However, `algpseudocode` is very well compatible with `algorithmicx` [See here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms#Typesetting_using_the_algorithmicx_package)